# Node.js copy async vs sync - which is faster?

Tags: node.js, performance, copy

I need to copy a directory content recursively in node.js and I found 2 common solutions:

1. ncp - async copy (using fs-extra.copy)
2. get all files using minimatch and copy them synchronously

I wonder which way is better in terms of performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`fs-extra`](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-fs-extra) author here -

Since Node.js is single process and single threaded, anything that is bound to I/O will block the process (until I/O is complete) unless you use the asynchronous APIs. Therefore, the async APIs will almost always be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should be using 'async' to gain the performance. Try to use a library like 
[async.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/async) to make things easier for you.

PS: If you need more help (code) post your existing code here.